# JComboBox не сворачивать список.

Tags: gui, java

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе элемента в JComboBox, список элементов не сворачивался. Например для того, чтобы можно было выделить несколько элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JComboBox` для этого точно не подойдёт. Если Вы хотите, чтобы компонент перекрывал собой часть ГУИ и при этом не был комбобоксом или `JMenu`, то окно будет единственным решением, насколько мне известно. Если Вам нужно, чтобы список отображался в окне, но выглядел и скрывался как комбобокс, то такие средства есть в SWT. Единственное, что Вам тогда останется продумать - какой элемент списка отображать в таком комбобоксе выбранным после скрытия списка, если было выбрано несколько элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, надо юзать `JList`.

Comment: А можно ли будет его сделать похожим на выпадающий список? Просто так места меньше он будет занимать. Или в этом случае его лучше открывать в диалоговом окне?